# simple g(n) such that f(n) = Θ(g(n))

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, mathematica-8

> f(n) = 4 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 4<sup>n</sup> + 20n<sup>5</sup>
>
> So, g(n) = 4<sup>n</sup>

Now our f(n) = O(g(n))

> 4 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 4<sup>n</sup> + 20n<sup>5</sup> ≤  c*4<sup>n</sup>
>
> How do we do this? I know how to do it for simple cases, but this one is far more complex. Would it go along the lines of removing the constant 4 and 20n<sup>5</sup> to then have 2<sup>n</sup> + 4<sup>n</sup> ≤ c*4<sup>n</sup>?
>
> Or would it be for any c > 4*2<sup>n</sup> + 20n<sup>5</sup>. It feels like a lame answer, so i'm going to assume i'm wrong. Would prefer if someone hinted at the idea of how to solve these problems rather than give me the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Hint / preparations

In the context of asymptotic analysis and, in this case, Big-O notation specifically; generally when wanting to prove that inequalities such as

```
4 * 2^n + 4^n + 20n^5 ≤ c*4^n,                               (+)

     for some constant c > 0,
     for n larger than some constant n0; n > n0
```

holds, we approach the left hand side expression term by term. Since we're free to choose *any* constants `c` and `n0` to show that `(+)` holds, we can always express the lower order terms as less or equal to (`≤`) the higher order term by making `n` *sufficiently large*, e.g., choosing the value of `n0` as we see fit.

---

## Solution (spoilers ahead!)

Below follows one way to show that `(+)` holds for some set of positive constants `c` and `n0`. Since you only asked for hints, I suggest you start with the section above, and return to this section in case you get stuck or want to verify the derivation you ended up using.

---

Term by term analysis (in terms of `4^n) of the left hand side expression of`(+)` follows.

***Term `4 * 2^n`:***

```
4 * 2^n = 4^n <=> (2*2)*2^n = (2^2)^n <=> 2^(n+2) = 2^(2n)
              <=> n+2 = 2n => n = 2

=> 4 * 2^n ≤ 4^n for n ≥ 2                                   (i)
```

***Term `4^n`:*** Trivial

***Term `20n^5`:***

```
for which n is 20 * n^5 = 4^n?
```

Graphical solution:

[image]

```
=> 20 * n^5 ≤ 4^n for n ≥~ 10.7 (choose 11)                  (ii)
```

---

Inserting inequalities `(i)` and `(ii)` in the lhs of `(+)` yields:

```
4 * 2^n + 4^n + 20n^5 ≤ 4^n + 4^n + 4^n = 3*4^n 
                                          ^
    for n>max(2,11)=11 <-- choice of n0   |
                                          choice of c
```

Hence, we have showed that `(+)` holds for constants `n0 = 11` and `c=3`. Naturally, the choice of these constants is not unique (in fact, if such constants exists, an infinite amount of them exists). Subsequently, the lhs of `(+)` is in `O(4^n)`.

Now, I note that your title mentions Big-Θ (whereas your question covers only Big-O). For deriving that lhs of `(+)` is `Θ(4^n)`, we need to find also a lower asymptotic bound on the lhs of `(+)` in terms of `4^n`. Since `n > 0`, this is, in this case, quite trivial:

```
4 * 2^n + 4^n + 20n^5 ≥ c2*4^n ? for n > n0 ?                (++)

=> 4 * 2^n + 4^n + 20n^5 ≥ 4^n, for n > 0
```

I.e., in addition to showing that `(+)` holds (which implies `O(4^n)`), we've shown that `(++)` holds for e.g. `c2 = 1` and (re-use) `n0 = 11`, which implies that lhs of `(+)` is `Θ(4^n)`.

---

One way to approach an asymptotic analysis of a function such as the left hand side of `(+)` would be to make use of the somewhat rigorous term-by-term analysis shown in this solution. In practice, however, we know that `4^n` will quickly dominate the lower order terms, so we could've just chosen a somewhat large `n0` (say 100) and tested, term by term, if the lower order terms could be replaced by the higher order term with less or equal to (`≤`) relation, given `n>n0`. Or, given in what context we need to make use of our asymptotic bounds, we could just glance at the function and, without rigour, directly state that the asymptotic behaviour of the function is naturally `O(4^n)`, due to this being the dominant term. This latter method should, imo, only be used *after* one has grasped how to formally analyse the asymptotic behaviour of functions and algorithms in the context of Big-O/-Omega and -Theta notation.

Answer (score 0):

The formal definition is

```
O(g(n)) = {f(n) | ∃c, n₀ : 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c g(n), ∀ n ≥ n₀}
```

But when you want to check if `f(x) ∈ O(g(n))`, you can use the simpler

```
         f(n)
lim sup ────── ≤ c
 n → ∞   g(n)
```

In this case,

```
         4*2ⁿ + 4ⁿ + 20n⁵
lim sup ────────────────── = 1
 n → ∞          4ⁿ
```

So yes, we can choose for example `c = 1`.